# Django suddenly gives "No module named "Django""

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Been making a blog and I've been busy/ill for 2 weeks, I have came back to it today and go to start my virtual environment, fine so I type `python manage.py runserver` and just get

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I tried installing django again but that didn't fix the problem

I dont know if it's because my postgres isn't running but when i type `psql` into my CLI I get `psql: error: FATAL:  role "toad" does not exist` which I can find literally nothing about when I google it

At this rate I'll be starting a new project and copy pasting everything across

Comment: try to run this command inside your virtual environment pip freeze and see if you get Django in output

Comment: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'```  pip and pip3 are in my venv folder, tried with both

Comment: try to run `python --version`

Comment: that works ```Python 3.8.10```

Comment: Did you activated your virtual environment ?

Comment: Yup get (venv) in my cli, in my settings.py also not working importing environ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234864/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-whisky-toad).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a new virtual env and re-installing all the packages I was using, not a great fix but still a fix

Answer (score -1):

I tried `(my path here)/venv/Scripts/python manage.py runserver` and it worked.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! 
When you provide a potential solution, please can you provide an indication of what is happening - in this case there might be unexpected consequences to your approach, such as what is in the python environment

Comment: What do you mean by "consequences such as what is in the python environment"? @EdwardMoffett